# How to use exiftool to set Windows specific metadata on a file

Tags: java, file, metadata, exif, exiftool

I'm using the exiftool from my java application to modify the metadata of different file. Mainly DOC, PDF, and JPEG.

I want to set the "comments" windows metadata property shown in this [image](http://res2.windows.microsoft.com/resbox/en/windows%20vista/main/d82eb014-63a1-418b-b12f-b58beb8909b8_14.png) to some information I grab from the database.

**Question**

Is there a way I can use ExifTool from my java application or from command line such that I can change the "comments" metadata properties on a file?

Answer (score 0):

While the link to your image is broken (not surprising 9 years on) I assume it's the 'Comments' section from the file's Properties context menu option.

[image]

For at least JPEG files:

`exiftool -XPComment="Data can include spaces" filename.jpg`

[image: Explorer example of that command output]

Comment: If both `UserComment` and `XPComment` are set Windows prefers to display `UserComment` thereby hiding XPComment. If UserComment is removed (`-UserComment=`) then XPComment will appear again in Explorer. Tag names from [ExifTool's Documentation](https://www.exiftool.org/TagNames/EXIF.html)